# How to make log4j print origin of message?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there a way to make Log4j-outputs include the origin of the message?
The following configuration via log4j.properties (which has been handed over to me...):

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %m%n
```

fails to print out the very important detail of what class is sending that message, and right now I could really need that bit on info!

Layna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Conversion Pattern Layout](http://www.codejava.net/coding/common-conversion-patterns-for-log4js-patternlayout)

For example, you can use ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c{1}:%M:%L - %m%n

Comment: THAT was the offending bit :). Thanks a lot, I had been trying to attack this basically every OTHER way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `%C` notation, you can see the package and the class name of the log origin.

So, you can use:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %m%n - %C
```